# Javascript simplify array indexing as arguments

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, ecmascript-6, refactoring

I have the following piece of code which works 100% but I can't help but feel their is a better way or more simple way of writing this or maybe not all and any help is always appreciated

```
const entity: any = response.organisation;

if (Array.isArray(responseKey)) {
  // responseKey e.g. ['site', 'accounts']
  // I feel this two declarations can be refactored
  const list = this.flattenGraphqlList<T>(entity[responseKey[0]][responseKey[1]]);
  const {totalCount} = entity[responseKey[0]][responseKey[1]];

  return {list, totalCount};
}

const list = this.flattenGraphqlList<T>(entity[responseKey]);
const {totalCount} = entity[responseKey];

return {list, totalCount};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do everything twice:

```
const entity: any = response.organisation;

const object = Array.isArray(responseKey) 
  ? entity[responseKey[0]][responseKey[1]] // responseKey e.g. ['site', 'accounts']
  : entity[responseKey];

const list = this.flattenGraphqlList<T>(object);
const {totalCount} = object;
return {list, totalCount};
```

I guess you can find a more descriptive name than `object` :-)

For the last lines, I personally would prefer not to use destructuring, but that's more a stylistic choice:

```
return {
  list: this.flattenGraphqlList<T>(object),
  totalCount: object.totalCount
};
```

Comment: `[].concat(responseKey).reduce((o, k) => o[k], entity)`

Comment: @JonasWilms yes, if dealing with arbitrarily-large arrays is necessary, `reduce` is a good idea. But I dislike relying on `isConcatSpreadable` and rather be explicit about distinguishing arrays from strings.